# How to decode pagination in JSON?

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to populate my website with products using the API of chinavasion.com. I've successfully fetch a list of products under a certain category but the response JSON only gives 10 products and a pagination which I literally don't know how to use, I'm guessing that it might be the one limiting the list of products echo'd?

Here is the sample JSON response:

```
{
 "products": [
  {
   "product_id": 19433,
   "model_code": "CVABR-C405",
   "short_product_name": "13.3 Inch Roof Mounted Car Monitor  ",
   "product_url": "http://www.chinavasion.com/china/wholesale/Car_Video/Roof_Monitors/13.3-Inch-Roof-Mounted-Car-Monitor/",
   "category_name": "Car Video",
   "category_url": "http://www.chinavasion.com/china/wholesale/Car_Video/",
   "subcategory_name": "Roof Monitors",
   "status": "In Stock"
  },
   .... and 9 more.

 "pagination": {
  "start": 0,
  "count": 10,
  "total": 53
 }
}
```

And here is my PHP so far, I just want to echo all the short product name of all the item, thing is I only get 10 items but there is a total of 53 items. (which can be seen on the sample JSON response pagination total)

```
<?php
$API_KEY = '4rxVx5-bxo7ldVQ5GcPSmX8XeqcSZoTnJnxF7xhRr8g.';
$url = "https://secure.chinavasion.com/api/getProductList.php";
$data = array(
'key' => $API_KEY,
'categories' => array('Car Video')
);

$content = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

foreach($response['products'] as $res)
{
    echo $res['short_product_name'],'<br />';
}
?>
```

So is there a way to fetch the other remaining 43 products at this point? I am not pretty sure if its possible or not as I am really pretty new to programming and haven't done JSON before, hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Try adding `'start' => 10` to your `$data` hash and see what happens.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen lol you beat me to it in the comments. Yeah, he just needs to pass an offset to get the next 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

next 10 items:

```
$API_KEY = '4rxVx5-bxo7ldVQ5GcPSmX8XeqcSZoTnJnxF7xhRr8g.';
$url = "https://secure.chinavasion.com/api/getProductList.php";
$data = array(
'key' => $API_KEY,
'categories' => array('Car Video'),
'pagination' => array('start' => 10)
);

$content = json_encode($data);
```

changing the 'pagination' => 'start' parameter you can set the starting item index.

**EDIT:**
you must insert the 'start' parameter inside the 'pagination' array.
An alternative way is to set the 'count' parameter to a big number. This way,you'll receive all items on a single call

```
$API_KEY = '4rxVx5-bxo7ldVQ5GcPSmX8XeqcSZoTnJnxF7xhRr8g.';
$url = "https://secure.chinavasion.com/api/getProductList.php";
$data = array(
'key' => $API_KEY,
'categories' => array('Car Video'),
'pagination' => array('count' => 999)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

That pagination array is there to indicate that there are more items. You just got to pass a `start` variable to get the next 10. Think of it as an offset in SQL.